I am creating signup page form my spring boot application in Angular and error is coming when hitting API though Gateway
I have created an application based on microservices architecture , So from postman its working fine, I have created gateway and authentication service and I am registering user and signin user by providing him JWT token. All is working fine but when I am hitting from my angular application through gateway it's showing error:

signup:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/register' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

But when I am hitting the service directly from angular page without gateway its working fine and user is also registered. So what can be the issue?
My gateway code:
private final RouteValidator validator;
private final JWTValidation jwtValidation;


@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        var request = exchange.getRequest();
        if (validator.isSecured.test(request)) {
            if (!request.getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
                throw new TokenMissingException("Token is not present");
            }
            String authHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                authHeader = authHeader.substring(7);
            }
            try {
                jwtValidation.validateToken(authHeader);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new TokenMissingException("Not authorized to access the request");
            }
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
}

package com.socials.Gateway.filter;

import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

@Component
public class RouteValidator {

    public static final List<String> apiList = List.of(
        "/auth/register",
        "/auth/getToken",
        "/auth/verify-account",
        "/auth/forgotPass",
        "/auth/resetPass",
        "/auth/refreshToken",
        "/eureka"
    );

    public Predicate<ServerHttpRequest> isSecured = serverHttpRequest ->
        apiList.stream().noneMatch(uri -> serverHttpRequest.getURI().getPath().contains(uri));
}

private static final String SECRET = "43d7640272c961817cbe57f9811a776dfde782048b35644ac1732778ea958806";

public void validateToken(final String token) {
    Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSigningKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
}

private SecretKey getSigningKey() {
    byte[] key = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET);
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(key);
}


You need to enable CORS to handle preflight requests. Postman does not send preflight requests, but when you test it from a web application, the browser sends a preflight request. Your gateway or backend system should have the mechanism to handle this.
In your case, you need to include the following code:
exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "Content-Type, Authorization");


It's not working,
Actually I have a question that when I am hitting from browser to the auth service directly
i.e. http://localhost:6969/auth/getToken its running fine and user is getting saved in databse.
But when passed through my gateway http://localhost:8080/auth/getToken its showing the CORS error.
